# ios Swift UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout Mirrored UI on switching UI Layout direction

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

whenever I switch language at runtime using the following code:

```
//set apple language to force localization use the intended language 
let userdef = UserDefaults.standard
userdef.set(["ar" /*or "en" to switch to english*/], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
userdef.synchronize()
//force all views to use propery layout direction
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = forceRightToLeft /*or .forceLeftToRight*/
//reload root view controller
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateInitialViewController()
```

Any collection view that uses Compositional Layout would be mirrored, not that the layout flipped but the content is mirrored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, must go old school:

1- for collection views, whenever created(either in storyboard or by code), fix the semantics to force LTR

2- whenever the language require RTL, apply transform with scaleX = -1, scaleY = 1 to the CollectioView itself.

3- for every view cell, apply another transform with scaleX = -1, scaleY = 1

**`Note`** for some layouts (mainly horizontal scrolling with dynamic item width) assigning transform to the collection view cell directly won't work and will leave the CollectionView Cell `mirrored` by the collection view transform.

3.1- so need to apply the transform to the top level subviews of the collection view cell.

To minimize the code, should wrap all the subViews of the collection view cell into one view filling the collection view cell, and apply the transform to it.